Reorder Countries from WooCommerce Checkout Country fields, keeping states sync
The Issue
I'm working on customizing the WooCommerce checkout page by reordering the countries in the billing_country and shipping_country dropdown fields. I've achieved this by using the woocommerce_checkout_fields filter to modify the fields' options.
However, after making these customizations, I'm facing an issue where the billing_state field doesn't update correctly when the billing_country field is changed. The state/province options remain the same, regardless of the selected country.
Current Code  (Previous Stackoverflow Post)
Here's the code I'm using to reorder the countries and apply the Select2 (selectWoo) functionality:
// Reorder and customize the country dropdowns
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reorder_checkout_country_dropdowns');
function reorder_checkout_country_dropdowns($fields)
{
    $countries_array = array_merge(
        array(
            'DE' => 'Germany',
            'AT' => 'Austria',
            'CH' => 'Switzerland',
            '-' => '------------',
        ),
        WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries()
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['type'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['options'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['options'] = $countries_array;

    return $fields;
}

// Enqueue JavaScript to apply Select2 functionality
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'enable_back_selectWoo_on_countries_dropdowns');
function enable_back_selectWoo_on_countries_dropdowns()
{
    wc_enqueue_js("$('#billing_country,#shipping_country').selectWoo();");
}

Attempted Solutions
This code reorders the countries in the dropdowns and applies the Select2 (selectWoo) functionality. However, it doesn't address the issue with the billing_state field not updating correctly when the billing_country is changed.
I've tried various approaches, such as adding an event listener to the billing_country field and updating the billing_state field accordingly, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works consistently.
The Question
How can I ensure that the billing_state field updates with the correct state/province options when the billing_country field is changed, even after customizing the country dropdown?
Image example to show the issue

As you can see in the image above, when "Austria - Österreich" is selected as the billing country in the WooCommerce checkout, the state selection field is incorrectly showing the states/provinces for "Germany" instead of the expected states/provinces for Austria.
The issue is not happening, when I comment out the second line add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reorder_checkout_country_dropdowns');

Have you checked what $countries_array actually looks like, after the array merge?

Thanks for your comment. The $countries_array looks correct, it outputs as intended. The issue I'm facing is related to the frontend JavaScript functionality that should update the billing_state field when the billing_country is changed. Even though the country dropdown is displaying correctly, the state/province field is not updating accordingly.

"it outputs as intended" - if by that you mean, the rendered select field shows the country names as intended ... that's not what I asked. Please verify what that array actually contains.

@CBroe have a look, that's the content of $countries_array after the array merged https://snipboard.io/kuMUq4.jpg

That looks okay. Is the problem actually related to this modified array - or has it to do with the fact that you added(?) select2 / selectWoo functionality to this, which wasn't applied to those fields before?

Yes, the problem is related to the modified array. Modifying the array leads to WooCommerce disabling the select2 functionality. In my previous post I got help how to activate select2 again. However, now I am struggling to activate select2 for billing state field in the checkout area. Usually select2 updates the states at the same time when you change the countries

"Modifying the array leads to WooCommerce disabling the select2 functionality." - not sure how that would make sense, if only the order of the country values changed? Are you sure you did not accidentally remove something else, that $fields previously contained?

@CBroe you see my code, I am 100% sure I did not remove anything else. I guess by reordering something changes internally. No idea. But as you see, I got an answer

Replace all your code with the following, to handle country states sync when changing country:
// Reorder and customize the country dropdowns
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reorder_checkout_country_dropdowns' );
function reorder_checkout_country_dropdowns( $fields ) {
    // Merge sorted countries, with unsorted ones
    $countries_array = array_merge( 
        array(
            'DE' => 'Germany',
            'AT' => 'Austria',
            'CH' => 'Switzerland',
            '-'  => '------------',
        ),
        WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries(), 
    );

    // Change field type from "country" to "select"
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['type'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['type'] = 'select';
    // Set sorted countries options
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['options'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['options'] = $countries_array;
    // Set correct input class for country field
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['input_class'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['input_class'] = ['country_to_state country_select'];
    
    return $fields;
}

Tested and works.
The JavaScript is not needed anymore.
